# Find the observable attached to 'value' in an event

Tags: knockout.js

In knockout.js I'm looking for a way to get the data or observable attached to a specific bindinghandler from within an event. In this case the observable attached to the `text` binding.

In example:

```
<div data-bind="text: homeGoals, click: handler }"></div>
<div data-bind="text: awayGoals, click: handler }"></div>
```

With the following model:

```
function Match()
{
    var self = this;

    self.homeGoals = ko.observable(0);
    self.awayGoals = ko.observable(0);

    self.handler = function(item, event)
    {   
        var observableBoundToText = // How to find out???
        observableBoundToText(42);
    }
}
```

So how to find out `observableBoundToText` ? I could fix this by making a separate object for 'Goals', with it's own handler, but I am hoping there is something simpler.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? The value binding will automatically set the observable values for you...

Comment: Sorry, by trying to simplify my problem for this question I made an illogical example ;) I adjusted the example.
In the end it is for some kind of dropdown functionality, but I hope the current example describes it fine.

Comment: why don't you just make the handler function take in a parameter, and pass either homeGoals or awayGoals?

Comment: Yeah that seems the most logical, and seems to be working! If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you just make the handler function take in a parameter, and pass either homeGoals or awayGoals?